# How to create HTML template with dynamic contents in it values to be merged from JSON by bbmustache

Tags: html, json, erlang, elixir, mustache

I need to have a HTML template and a JSON mapping, which will be injected into template by bbmustache.

My requirement is that the content in template can be dynamic. What I mean is -

> Let's assume, in the html template defined, there is a table having 3 rows. But the JSON payload can have only
> values for 2 rows and the 3rd row will not be required. Similarly, the
> JSON payload can have values for 4 rows, in that case I need to add an
> additional row in the table.

How can I have a dynamic template?

Using Elixir/Erlang, bbmustache.

Comment: Found one approach.
1. template.html


<table>
      {{#items}}
      <tr>
        <th>{{name}}<th>
      </tr>
      {{/items}}
    </table>

2. mapping.json

{
  "items": [
    {"name": "red"},
    {"name": "green"},
    {"name": "blue"}
  ]
  
}


This approach works.

But is there any other approach which can be used.
Please suggest any reference or any better approach, thanks.